# SQL Server After Insert/Update/Delete Trigger - data type error

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger that automatically fills an audit table when a change is made in my main table.

The trigger mainly taken from here: https://newbedev.com/log-record-changes-in-sql-server-in-an-audit-table is:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TR_Price_AUDIT] ON [dbo].[PriceList] FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
   AS
           DECLARE @bit            INT,
                   @field          INT,
                   @maxfield       INT,
                   @char           INT,
                   @fieldname      VARCHAR(128),
                   @TableName      VARCHAR(128),
                   @PKCols         VARCHAR(1000),
                   @sql            VARCHAR(2000),
                   @UpdateDate     VARCHAR(21),
                   @UserName       VARCHAR(128),
                   @Type           CHAR(1),
                   @PKSelect       VARCHAR(1000),
                   @lastAuditPK BIGINT,
                   @AuditGroupPK VARCHAR(2000)


           --You will need to change @TableName to match the table to be audited.
           SELECT @TableName = 'PriceList'

           SELECT @UserName = SYSTEM_USER,
                  @UpdateDate = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), GETDATE(), 126)

                   SELECT @AuditGroupPK = (SELECT top 1 Id FROM [Audit].[dbo].[PriceAudit] Order by Id desc) + 1
                --  SELECT @AuditGroupPK = convert(int,3)
           -- Action
           IF EXISTS (
                  SELECT *
                  FROM   INSERTED
              )
               IF EXISTS (
                      SELECT *
                      FROM   DELETED
                  )
                   SELECT @Type = 'U'
               ELSE
                   SELECT @Type = 'I'
           ELSE
               SELECT @Type = 'D'

           -- get list of columns
           SELECT * INTO #ins
           FROM   INSERTED

           SELECT * INTO #del
           FROM   DELETED

           -- Get primary key columns for full outer join
           SELECT @PKCols = COALESCE(@PKCols + ' and', ' on') 
                  + ' i.[' + c.COLUMN_NAME + '] = d.[' + c.COLUMN_NAME + ']'
           FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS pk,
                  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE c
           WHERE  pk.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
                  AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
                  AND c.TABLE_NAME = pk.TABLE_NAME
                  AND c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME

           -- Get primary key select for insert
           SELECT @PKSelect = COALESCE(@PKSelect + '+', '') 
                  + '''<[' + COLUMN_NAME 
                  + ']=''+convert(varchar(100),
           coalesce(i.[' + COLUMN_NAME + '],d.[' + COLUMN_NAME + ']))+''>'''
           FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS pk,
                  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE c
           WHERE  pk.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
                  AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
                  AND c.TABLE_NAME = pk.TABLE_NAME
                  AND c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME

                  -- Get primary key select for insert
           SELECT @PKSelect = 'convert(varchar(100),
           coalesce(i.[' + COLUMN_NAME + '],d.[' + COLUMN_NAME + ']))'
           FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS pk,
                  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE c
           WHERE  pk.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
                  AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
                  AND c.TABLE_NAME = pk.TABLE_NAME
                  AND c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME



           IF @PKCols IS NULL
           BEGIN
               RAISERROR('no PK on table %s', 16, -1, @TableName)

               RETURN
           END

           SELECT @field = 0,
                  -- @maxfield = MAX(COLUMN_NAME) 
                  @maxfield = -- FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName


                  MAX(
                      COLUMNPROPERTY(
                          OBJECT_ID(TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + @TableName),
                          COLUMN_NAME,
                          'ColumnID'
                      )
                  )
           FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
           WHERE  TABLE_NAME = @TableName






           WHILE @field < @maxfield
           BEGIN
               SELECT @field = MIN(
                          COLUMNPROPERTY(
                              OBJECT_ID(TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + @TableName),
                              COLUMN_NAME,
                              'ColumnID'
                          )
                      )
               FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
               WHERE  TABLE_NAME = @TableName
                      AND COLUMNPROPERTY(
                              OBJECT_ID(TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + @TableName),
                              COLUMN_NAME,
                              'ColumnID'
                          ) > @field

               SELECT @bit = (@field - 1)% 8 + 1

               SELECT @bit = POWER(2, @bit - 1)

               SELECT @char = ((@field - 1) / 8) + 1





               IF SUBSTRING(COLUMNS_UPDATED(), @char, 1) & @bit > 0
                  OR @Type IN ('I', 'D')
               BEGIN
                   SELECT @fieldname = COLUMN_NAME
                   FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                   WHERE  TABLE_NAME = @TableName
                          AND COLUMNPROPERTY(
                                  OBJECT_ID(TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + @TableName),
                                  COLUMN_NAME,
                                  'ColumnID'
                              ) = @field



                   SELECT @sql = 
                          '
           insert into [Audit].[dbo].[PriceAudit] (    Type, 
           TableName, 
           PK, 
           FieldName, 
           OldValue, 
           NewValue, 
           UpdateDate, 
           UserName, GroupId)
           select ''' + @Type + ''',''' 
                          + @TableName + ''',' + @PKSelect
                          + ',''' + @fieldname + ''''
                          + ',CAST(CAST(d.' + @fieldname + ' AS nvarchar(1000)) AS varchar(1000))'
                          + ',CAST(CAST(i.' + @fieldname + ' AS nvarchar(1000)) AS varchar(1000))'
                          + ',''' + @UpdateDate + ''''
                          + ',''' + @UserName + ''''
                          + ',' + @AuditGroupPK + ''
                          
                          + ' from #ins i full outer join #del d'
                          + @PKCols
                          
                          + ' where i.' + @fieldname + ' <> d.' + @fieldname 
                          + ' or (i.' + @fieldname + ' is null and  d.'
                          + @fieldname
                          + ' is not null)' 
                          + ' or (i.' + @fieldname + ' is not null and  d.' 
                          + @fieldname
                          + ' is null)' 

EXEC (@sql)
                          

                         

                   
                   
               END
           END
```

It mainly works, but when the field contains data like '44.154214' it throws the error:
table Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '44.154214' to data type int.

I'm not sure why it's trying to set it to be an int. I want it to be a varchar.

I've tried casting it to varchar but that hasn't helped. Is there anything I can do to make this work?

Comment: A very quick look at that code, and it looks like SQL that has no business being in a trigger. Triggers should have as minimal impact as possible and the above looks like that is *far* from the case. I smell an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info).

Comment: It also looks like the sort of code that should be custom written per table, rather than doing a dynamic SQL bodge. Never mind that, it has a huge flaw: it only supports DML of exactly one row. And it uses variable coelscing, which is deprecated and oculd return incorrect results

Comment: It sounds like you're both not fans of this. The aim is to have an audit table so I can review all of the changes done. If I code a trigger specifically for the table I want to monitor, would that be an OK solution. Or are there better options I can use?

Comment: You're right in that neither myself or @Charlieface are fans, Jimmy. What is the actual goal you're trying to achieve here then? You say you want to have an "audit table", but what is this audit table going to store? Is it something that could be controlled by enforcing users use procedures, for example. Do all the tables *need* to insert this data into a Audit table? Do the tables that do need auditing all need to use a single Audit table (which would therefore need to be denormalised)? Could something like temporal tables better suit the business need, for example?

Comment: Yeah that's not as bad, but temporal tables or Change Data Capture might be even better solutions

Comment: Evolve - no one should be using [old-style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)